# Is there a way to record 'on board' audio on iPad?

Tags: ipad, audio, ios-appstore

Related to this question: [What cable do I need to go iPad audio out to macbook air mic in?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126458/what-cable-do-i-need-to-go-ipad-audio-out-to-macbook-air-mic-in) which is asking about cables to record iPad audio on another device.

This question is: is there a way to record audio generated on the iPad on the iPad itself? For example, are there any audio recording apps that can record in the background while audio is being created in another app?

It's a bit hard to search for as there are a lot of apps that allow you to record audio via the external mic, but I'm specifically looking to record audio generated from the iPad itself (such as from a synthesizer or drum machine app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no.  On a stock iOS device, the OS security sandbox prevents any app from recording, or otherwise accessing in any way, the audio generated by any other app, unless that other app explicitly exports its audio (via AudioBus or Inter-App Audio).  Some (but not all) synthesizer and drum machines (etc.) apps document support for such.

Comment: Hmm...that makes sense (security wise). The app in particular is TF7 which claims: "Inter-app Audio : use TF7 in DAW apps like Garageband and Beatmaker 2!". I haven't loaded GarageBand on here, but does that mean perhaps GarageBand can record TF7 audio? (If so, can I export from GarageBand to audio file to send to someone?)

Comment: That's one big reason GarageBand supports inter-app audio.